# Why does ozone cleave alkenes?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I am studying additional reactions in organic chemistry and I am confused as to why ozone cleaves double bonds? I already know the mechanism of what happens but can anyone give a more conceptual understanding of why this occurs?

Comment: The mechanism actually tells you why this occurs. It's a step-by-step description. The overall reaction is favored. Each step is favored or provides easy access to a favored step.

Comment: Not all reactions are driven by... wait, I think I already said that.

Answer (score 3):

Analysis of the [frontier molecular orbitals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frontier_molecular_orbital_theory) of the alkene and ozone molecules easily and elegantly predicts the occurrence of the first step of this reaction:

[image]

The actual cleavage step forms a carbonyl and carbonyl oxide—a pair of molecules that are electronically identical to the starting reagents, but are thermodynamically favored over their regenration:

$$ \small
\begin{array}{lcc}
\hline
& \text{Bond Dissociation} & & \text{Bond Dissociation}\\
\text{Bond} & \text{Enthalpy}\ \mathrm{(kJ\ mol^{-1})} & \text{Bond} & \text{Enthalpy}\ \mathrm{(kJ\ mol^{-1})} \\
\hline
\ce{C-C} & 347 &\ce{C=C} & 614\\
\ce{O-O} & 146 & \ce{O=O} & 495\\
\ce{C-O} & 358 & \ce{C=O} & 745^{[1]}\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

[image]

Formation of the secondary ozonide is also thermodynamically favored:

[image]

---

<sub>$^{[1]}$[Bond Dissociation Enthalpy Tables](http://chem.libretexts.org/Core/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry/Chemical_Bonding/General_Principles_of_Chemical_Bonding/Bond_Energies)</sub>